# インストールされているソフトウェアのパスの取得方法

Tags: c#, windows

いつもお世話になっております。

PC にインストールされているソフトウェアの情報を取得するツールを開発中です。
インストールされているソフトウェアの一覧は以下のレジストリを参照することで取得することができました。

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

上記レジストリにある "InstallLocation" が、そのソフトウェアのインストール先のパスだと認識しております。
ただ、ソフトウェアによっては "InstallLocation" の値が空になっているものがあり、そのソフトウェアについてはインストール先のパスが分からない状況です。
"InstallLocation" の値が空になっているソフトウェアのインストール先のパスを取得方法はありますでしょうか？
また、レジストリを参照する以外でインストールソフトウェアの情報を取得する方法が他にございましたら併せてご教示いただければ幸いです。

よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: レジストリも他にあと2つ場所があるようです。[Windows10でインストール済みアプリの一覧をコマンドで収集する方法](https://4thsight.xyz/26528) 他にはクリーナーソフトと呼ばれるもので情報収集できるかも。[無料クリーナーソフト一覧](https://freesoft-100.com/pasokon/cleaner.html) 商用だと資産管理ツールとかでしょうか。[IT資産管理ツールとは？目的・仕組みをわかりやすくご紹介](https://www.aspicjapan.org/asu/article/810), [【22年版】IT資産管理ツールのおすすめ14選を徹底比較](https://it-trend.jp/it_asset_management/article/181-0002)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
ご教示いただいたサイトで紹介されていたレジストリを参照してみましたが同じような状況でした。情報をいただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

歴史的経緯もあり、インストーラー仕様は統一されておらず、最悪アンインストール時に実行すべきファイル名だけの場合もあります。
MSI（Windows Installer）が現在の標準、と言いたいところですがストアアプリが登場したりMSIXが登場したり、相変わらずの乱立状態です。

そのため、回答としては「存在しない」となります。

---

一応、MSIについてもう少し説明しておくと、[Windows Installer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-portal)として説明されており、[内部のデータベース仕様](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/database-tables)もあります。APIもありますが質問のような用途には[スクリプトインターフェース](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/automation-interface)も用意されています。
（スクリプトインターフェースはC#の`dynamic`で扱えますので）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。取得する方法は存在しないとのことで承知しました。レジストリ以外から取得できないか、他の方法を模索したいと思います。